# Cypress adds js files alongside my ts files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webstorm, cypress

I'm using Cypress in TypeScript, in WebStorm. I'd been working on project A1 for a few weeks, I added Cypress, I add TS to Cypress, and then things started getting a little funny, including js files being added alongside the ts files, both in Cypress and in my src folder. (tsx files didn't do this, only ts)

So I restarted the project: I created a whole new Create React App project, A2, and started dragging the files one by one (or folder by folder) from A1 to A2. I added the Cypress files to A2 by running `cypress open` when A2 had no cypress files in it, which caused Cypress to add its files. Then I added my tests from A1 (copying code into new files, not copying the files) and set up various config files and stuff such that:

- TS recognizes my custom cypress commands
- No extra JS files are created

Then I deleted all the files in the A1 project and dragged in all the files, minus the `node_modules` folder, from A2, and ran `yarn install`.

Everything works, except the Cypress folder still creates js files alongside the ts files.

It's very hard to pinpoint the actual moment when this happens: I had written this post and abandoned it because things seemed to be working fine. But then a few hours later I noticed the js files were back! Only in the Cypress folders, including ALL ts files in the Cypress folders (/integration, /plugins, etc).

Here's some tsconfigs:

`cypress/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress"]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts", "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

`<project_root>/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Oh no, and now all of a sudden it's making js files out of ts in my `src` folder!

When I delete all these extra js files (which, in the src folder, generate warnings in the running app), I also get these kind of warnings from WebStorm:

> Oops! Something went wrong! :( ESLint: 6.7.2. ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-import". (The package "eslint-plugin-import" was not found when loaded as a Node module from the directory "/Users/tuzmacbookpro2017/dev/Sunrise/IVD".) It's likely that the plugin isn't installed correctly. Try reinstalling by running the following: npm install eslint-plugin-import@latest --save-dev The plugin "eslint-plugin-import" was referenced from the config file in "nginx/front_end/package.json » eslint-config-react-app". If you still can't figure out the problem, please stop by https://gitter.im/eslint/eslint to chat with the team.

The react server and the cypress server and runner all seem happy though.

Help! What's with these js files? (I know TS transpiles ts into js or whatever, but usually the files don't actually show up like this)

Comment: please make sure that **Recompile on changes** is not enabled in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**

Comment: Thanks @lena. This appears to fix it. However, it's hard to check because for some reason my project pane file view isn't auto-refreshing, I have to select "Refresh VSC Changes". I'm pretty sure this is a recent issue. Is there a fix?

Comment: Not sure what action you refer to... Please provide exact steps to repeat

Comment: @lena See new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63850843/6826164

Comment: @lena I have been seeing this same thing recently and it seems related to Webstorm because if I have webstorm open when I'm running cypress tests I get this issue and if I close webstorm first it doesn't happen.I already had recompile on change disabled for typescript. I didn't previously have this issue. I'm not sure if the upgrade to webstorm 2020 caused it to start or if it was already happening before that.

Comment: @lena it seems like webstorm is reading the js files and preventing cypress from cleaning them up after its runs or something maybe, but I don't know.

Comment: @lena actually I take that back. I was in the wrong project when I checked that setting before. Disabling Recompile on changes did fix it for me too. That should be an actual answer, not just a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that **Recompile on changes** is not enabled in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to the configuration file
`false` value to the next fields:

- fixturesFolder
- integrationFolder
- pluginsFile
- etc...

(Or just for the fields you need of course.)

documentation:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Folders-Files

Comment: I don't want to disable the folders, I want to stop typescript from generating the js files.