# WebStorm file pane doesn't automatically refresh

Tags: webstorm

My project pane file view isn't auto-refreshing when there are external changes, until I to select "Refresh VSC Changes". I'm pretty sure this is a recent issue.

To reproduce, for example:

1. Enable "Recompile on Changes" in TypeScript Settings (just for testing here)
2. Make a change to a typescript file. TypeScript recompiles and adds js files alongside ts files.
3. These new files aren't visible in WebStorm.
4. Select "Refresh VSC Changes"
5. Now the files are visible.

Comment: VFS had never refreshed automatically when re-compiling files, you have to reload changes manually with **File > Reload All from Disk** to get the tree updated

Comment: Weird, I guess I just hadn't noticed it. Well, asked and answered. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are referring to other cases when IDE actually looks for changes. E.g. When switching focus from another app back to IDE; when using File Watcher (if configured correctly it will look for changes in files mentioned in "Output paths to refresh" field). But overall it is what lena said: IDE does not auto refresh file system looking for changes.